# Make a global when true in Laravel 5 Model

Tags: php, laravel-5

I come from cakePHP where it is possible to have every get or list query to include a standard where "something = something" in the Model. Per function in the controller this can be ignored, but for all others this is used.

Now I am wondering how to do this in Laravel 5. I would like to add something like below code in the Model or in the Controller (but preferably in the Model):

```
public function __construct(Page $page) {
    $page->where('is_active', 1);
}
```

So that when running any query on the pages table it will only give me active pages. Except when I manually add `where('is_active', 0)` or something else to include all active and inactive pages.

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of what you want can be achieved by using a query scope on the model.

You'd put something like this in your model:

```
/**
 * Scope a query to only include active users.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
*/
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->where('active', 1);
}
```

And then when you wanted to use it you'd do something like this:

```
$users = App\User::active()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

It doesn't set a default for all queries, but it might be a better long term solution.  Docs are here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Thanx Andrew. Exactly what I was looking for. The scope functionality is now clear to me also :)